# SQL Server 2012 Number of Catalogs Limit?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've got a customer who currently has about 500 catalogs (each catalog is 100's of customers inside a single corp). It took them about 10 year to get this far. Now, they are adding smaller catalogs (and more of them) at about 50 catalogs a month.

My understanding is that there are no hard limits on the number of catalogs in a SQL Server database but I'm thinking for things like replication and management tools it would get hard to manage.

Am I wrong? If not, what are the specific, concrete things that will go wrong when getting to thousands if not tens of thousands of catalogs (or is that OK).

Comment: Appears to be a classic databases gone wild scenario. Strongly suggest getting the technical leadership to invest time to rethink the architecture and technologies, including things like Azure SQL DB where Microsoft deals with most of the management complexities. Apart from the issues mentioned by zedfoxus below, one problem that you can't fix is the startup time in the event of an instance and/or server restart. The databases in the instance start sequentially and you have no way to set priority. Imagine each taking 15s, how long before the last DB is online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server allows 32767 maximum databases in a single instance. Having hundreds of databases (catalogs) on a single SQL Server instance happens more often than we would think. It does offers backup/restore/high availability challenges.

Underpowered server(s) could be one challenge. One will need a very beefy hardware when going to many hundreds and thousands of databases, especially if they are all very active. One will need very robust disk structure, a significant amount of memory and ample powerful CPUs. Adding CPUs means additional cost in licensing SQL Server.

Bandwidth/network contention may also occur. Server-wide settings will be required at some point. It may help some databases and may hurt others. One would have to stay on top of transaction logs ensuring that backup of a few giant databases doesn't bog down the entire server.

Maintenance overhead will be a challenge. Such servers are likely to be clustered and highly available. That means, more discussions on architecture will have to happen. You could do volume mirroring on NetApp-like system to restore volumes on standby system, or you could do traditional mirroring/log shipping etc. and they happen per-database, not by an instance. Discussions will have to happen on whether all databases will ship to another cluster or different clusters, and how they will be brought to life if the main server goes down.

These are all normal discussions when situation demands it; and in some organizations, such demands are common. Large number of catalogs on a busy server means multiple DBAs - overheard costs, power requirements, upgrade licenses, DR, HA etc. will all invoke discussions. If DBAs don't get along, this can pose a personnel related challenge.

However, organizations have done such kinds of things and have managed risks appropriately. The technology is there to do such things. One just needs to manage personnel and technology to get the best value at a reasonable costs.

Comment: It would be nice to include a link to the answer that shows the limit:  [Databases per instance of SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)